# Cache dependency in gitlab-ci / docker

Tags: php, docker, caching, gitlab

I don't know how to do cache dependency in **gitlab-ci -> docker**. 
My project has 82 dependencies and they get very slow.. (vendor is in gitignore)

**Full process:**

change local file **->** comit and push to repo remote **->** run gitlab-ci **->** build docker image **->** push image to other server **->** publish image

**My example project:**

- app -> my files (html, img, php, css, anything)
- gitlab-ci.yml
- composer.json
- composer.lock
- Makefile
- Dockerfile

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM hub.myserver.test/image:latest
ADD . /var/www
CMD cd /var/www
RUN composer install --no-interaction
RUN echo "#done" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
```

**gitlab-ci:**

```
build:
    script: 
        - make build
    only:
        - master
```

**Makefile:**

```
all: build

build:
    docker build hub.myserver.test/new_image .
```

How I can caching dependencies (composer.json)? I do not want to download libraries from scratch.

Comment: This is for Travis but should be useful for your case. https://blog.wyrihaximus.net/2015/07/composer-cache-on-travis/
Remember that you can only cache items (files/directory) that are inside the build folder in gitlab-ci

Comment: I didn't notice that it is more complicated to use cache with docker. But this [stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39772423/7786148) might help you ?

Answer (score 1):

Usually it's not a good idea to run `composer install` inside your image. I assume you need eventually to run your php app not composer itself, so you can avoid having it in production.

One possible solution is to split app image creation into 2 steps:

1. Install everything outside image
2. Copy ready-made files to image

**.gillab-ci.yml**

```
stages:
  - compose
  - build

compose:
  stage: compose
  image: composer       # or you can use your hub.myserver.test/image:latest
  script:
    - composer install  # install packages
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - vendor/         # save them for next job

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker build -t hub.myserver.test/new_image .
    - docker push hub.myserver.test/new_image
```

So in Dockerfile you just copy files from artifacts dir from first stage to image workdir:

```
# you can build from your own image
FROM php

COPY . /var/www

WORKDIR /var/www
# optional, if you want to replace CMD of base image
CMD [ "php", "./index.php" ]
```

Another good consideration is that you can test your code before building image with it. Just add `test` job between `compose` and `build`.

[Live example @ gitlab.com](https://gitlab.com/so-answer/composer/pipelines/44040343)